# Get top x items from an array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
array(10) { [0]=> int(5) 
            [1]=> int(8) 
            [2]=> int(2)
            [3]=> int(0)
            [4]=> int(1) 
            [5]=> int(9) 
            [6]=> int(1) 
            [7]=> int(0) 
            [8]=> int(5) 
            [9]=> int(4) 
          }
```

Ok, so I have an array as above. What I would like to do is get the top x items, change them into 1 and the rest into 0 without messing with the keys so that I can implode it back in the correct order. So if I want top 5, the result should be something like:

```
array(10) { [0]=> int(1) 
            [1]=> int(1) 
            [2]=> int(0)
            [3]=> int(0)
            [4]=> int(0) 
            [5]=> int(1) 
            [6]=> int(0) 
            [7]=> int(0) 
            [8]=> int(1) 
            [9]=> int(1) 
          }
```

I tried using `sort`, but I think it messes up the keys.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try reading about the [different variants of sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), some of which maintain the keys

Comment: Your question is incorrect. You don't look for the x top elements. Actually you want to set all items to 1, if the value >= 5.

Comment: @djot Nope. I'm looking for top x elements. The above array is just an example. Anyways, I think I will be able to do it using `arsort` and `ksort` after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkBaker. Fixed it using `arsort` and `ksort`.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, I don't know If I understand question, but maybe:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $topX; $i++)
  $arr[$i] = (int)1;
for ($i = $topX+1;$i < count($arr); $i++)
  $arr[$i] = (int)0;
```

Or add IF:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
  $arr[$i] = ($arr[$i] < $maxVal) ? (int)1 : (int)0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess this is what you are looking for. I believe that the code is self-explain because I have comment all the important concept in the code.

```
<?php
    function top(&$arr, $top, $start = 0)
    {
        if (count($arr) > $start) {
            // count the number of element that larger 
            // than the element at start position
            $count = 0;     
            for($i = $start + 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
                if ($arr[$start] < $arr[$i]) $count++;
            }

            // if there are more than [$top] number of element
            // that is larger than this element
            // it cannot be in the [$top] largest number
            if ($count >= $top) {
                $arr[$start] = 0;
            } else {
                $arr[$start] = 1;
                $top -= 1;
            }

            // continue to next element
            top($arr, $top, $start + 1);
        }
    }

    $arr = array(5, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 0, 5, 4);
    top($arr, 5);
    var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`asort()` sort an array and maintain index association.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has some pretty neat array-functions you can work with. Here's one approach:

```
<?php

function change_top_items($array, $top_x) {

    // first, sort the values and preserve the keys
    uasort($array, function($a, $b) {

         if ($a == $b) return 0;             
         return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;

    });

    // put the top x values in an array
    $compare = array_slice($array, -$top_x);

    // now walk through the original array
    $modified = array_map(function($value) use ($compare) {

            // if the current value is in the top x array
            // set it to 1, else set it to 0
        return in_array($value, $compare) ? 1 : 0;

    }, $array);

    // now sort the modified array by keys again and return it
    ksort($modified);

    return $modified;

}

$a = [5, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 0, 5, 4];

print_r(change_top_items($a, 5));
```

And that's pretty much it.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
)
```

Here's a working exapmple: http://3v4l.org/HI2EH - As you can also see there, I've used a syntax which is only valid for PHP 5.4+. This concerns the short array notation and the use of closures. But this code can easily be converted into a syntax of the previous PHP versions.